# How exactly do you stub methods or variables in java?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, testng

So for example, let's say I have a basic POJO like this.

```
public class Stuff {

   private OtherStuff otherStuff;

   ...

   public void RunOtherStuff() {
       otherStuff.run();
   }

}
```

How exactly would you test that RunOtherStuff calls otherStuff.run?

I'm using TestNG as my base testing framework right now and am completely open to any Java framework that'd allow me to test this similar to how'd you use rspec etc. in Rails and Ruby.

Comment: Normally you'd make `OtherStuff` injectable and send in a mock. If you can't do that, you could use something like Mockito, EasyMock, PowerMock, or a combination to make an observable `OtherStuff`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Android SDK but if we're talking Java I recomment Mockito: http://code.google.com/p/mockito/

Comment: So how would you do it with Mockito?

Comment: I also found PowerMock user to add with Mockito to stub private etc. just like in rspec for the ROR folks.

Answer (score 0):

You'd create a setter for `otherStuff` and before you call `RunOtherStuff()` you'd call `setOtherStuff(myFake)`

```
public class Stuff {

   private OtherStuff otherStuff;

   public void setOtherStuff(OtherStuff otherStuff) {
       this.otherStuff = otherStuff;
   }

   ...

   public void RunOtherStuff() {
       otherStuff.run();
   }

}
```

Then your test can be written like this:

```
private Stuff stuff;
private boolean runWasCalled;

public void setUp() {
    stuff = new Stuff();
    stuff.setOtherStuff(new OtherStuff() {
        public void run() {
            runWasCalled = true;
        }
    });
}



public void testThatOtherStuffRunMethodIsCalled() {
    stuff.RunOtherStuff();

    assertTrue(runWasCalled);
}
```

Comment: This works but it seems like a lot of code just to do a simple thing such as verify if something runs, I'd have to rewrite parts of a class.

Comment: That's true.  There are lots of mocking frameworks to make it less code.  Look into [mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/).

Answer (score 0):

Write a `MockOtherStuff` which is basically a subclass of OtherStuff. Override `run()` method and say like `System.out.println('Run is called');`

Now, have a setter for `OtherStuff` in `Stuff` class and pass your mocker.

**EDIT:**

To assert, you may have a boolean variable say runWasCalled (default to false) and set it to true inside `MocOtherStuff.run()`

Comment: Problem with this is you can't assert that it got into the `MockOtherStuff.run()` method with this alone

Comment: yes, you're right. It'd need a boolean variable say runWasCalled which can be set inside `run()` and that can be asserted.